# Enviar FormData con Fetch metodo post y recibir en Express JS no me funciona

Tags: nodejs, express, post, fetch, formdata

estoy tratando de enviar a traves de fetch un FormData con el metodo post a traves del siguiente codigo:

```
$loginForm.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let loginForm = new FormData($loginForm);
  console.log(loginForm.get('emailLogin'),loginForm.get('passwordLogin'));
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/login',{
    method: "POST",
    body: loginForm
  })
});
```

con el console.log obtengo los valores del formulario correctamente, pero al recibirlos en node/express con el siguiente codigo:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  let respuesta = req.body.emailLogin;
  console.log(respuesta);
  res.status(200);
})
```

no logro recibir los datos del formulario, me da undefined y si miro en la parte network de la consola de firefox me dice que estoy recibiendo una req post sin headers ni parametros ni respuesta ni nada.
Probe mandar el formulario con el submit sin usar fetch y lo recibe perfectamente.
Tambien probe mandar un objeto json en el body de la peticion y tambien recibo una peticion post vacia en network.
Trate de usar body-parser para urlencoded y json pero estan depreciados.
En el tutorial de YT de donde saque esto le funciona, que me esta faltando?

Comment: El servidor desde donde sirves el html con el fetch, es el mismo que tu aplicacion express? Si no es así es muy posible que sea un problema de CORS

Comment: estoy en local, aunque ya encontre la causa, la solucion es convertir los datos del form data a json del lado del front o usar en el back una libreria como multer. Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

En el caso que esté bien configurado tu CORS, puede ser que tu servidor no está preparado para manejar la petición `OPTIONS` para las [peticiones verificadas](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#solicitudes_verificadas).
En tal caso, añade esto a tu servidor de express:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());

app.options('/login', function(req, res) {
  // Útil para hacer algún tipo de verificación previo al código de tu controlador POST
  res.status(200)
})
app.post('/login', function(req, res){
  let respuesta = req.body.emailLogin;
  console.log(respuesta);
  res.status(200);
})
```